# apache not displaying php pages, offering them for download instead

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

we are trying to setup apache (apache 2 in this case, although apache does the same thing) and html pages display just fine, however, any php pages linked into buttons on the front page are offered for download rather than being displayed.

Any ideas what we have missed?  Its proving difficult to search on this in google as the terms are so heavily used elsewhere.

I know this is a bit general, but we have tried adding types to the to the apache.conf (or httpd.conf for apache1) are having no joy at all.

Thanks.

Peter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a PHP script handler.

The configuration lines in Apache2 that you're missing look something like this:

```
# Use for PHP 5.x:
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script php 

# Add index.php to your DirectoryIndex line:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

With something like Apache on Linux, it's typically installed when you include the PHP packages into your distribution.

What OS are you running this on?

Comment: also, don't forget to restart your apache server after making changes to the configuration. simply adding the types and letting it go isn't enough. only mentioning this as the OP mentioned adding the types to his configuration.

Comment: OK.. no joy on this one.  The setup I have is loading the php module and handler in a file from mods-enabled which has the configuration mentioned above, but still, after restarting the server, I'm getting the same behavior.

This is running on a Ubuntu installation.

Peter.

Comment: Turns out that a re-install did the trick.  No idea why, the configs seem to be the same, but its all good now.

Thanks all.

Comment: Also, don't forget to clear your browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this

```
a2enmod php5
```

then restart apache2 with

```
rcapache2 graceful
```

on a suse style linux

Comment: the a2enmod command comes back with "This module is already enabled!"
and I have no rcapache2 (but I guess /etc/init.d/apache2 restart is the same).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking on this question for a while finding a lot of Linux answers and not too many Windows answers.

Here was the solution for me:

If you already put the `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` into the `httpd.conf` file for Apache, then you do not need it in your `.htaccess` file on your webpage.  I found deleting it from my `.htaccess` made php render.