# Strange error with Apache & PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is PHP script downloaded instead of executed](https://serverfault.com/questions/25227/why-is-php-script-downloaded-instead-of-executed)
>   [What causes PHP pages to consistently download instead of running normally](https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally)

I have searched for this issue and did not find anything, so I apoligise if there is in fact an article on this matter.

Basically, I installed Apache and PHP via `aptitude install <package>` on Debian 6. HTML pages render in a browser perfectly fine. When I try to render a page with the extension `*.php` the file is downloaded, not parsed and the output not shown. So far I have been testing a simple
 `<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

Thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/140954/apache-not-displaying-php-pages-offering-them-for-download-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed the Apache PHP package that links them together. On Ubuntu, a Debian derivative, the package is called libapache2-mod-php5 . I am not sure if it has the same name in Debian 6, but it will likely be similar.